# How to use empty placeholder text

Tags: php, wordpress, placeholder

Well the question is pretty clear. How could i use text from a placeholder e.g from the below text. I've been searching a lot for this and haven't found a solution. Your help would be appreciated.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="YYYY, MM - 1, DD" name="director_date"
 value="<?php print get_option('director_date');
 ?>" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by use?

Comment: @smistry E.g if no text is written in the box the placeholder text would be used

Comment: That happens on its own? Do you mean when the form is submitted you want the placeholder as the data?

Comment: Yes that is what i want

Comment: @smistry could you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non javascript solution, you'll have to test for an empty field on form submittal.

```
<?php
if(empty($_REQUEST['director_date']))
{
    $dir_date = "YYYY, MM - 1, DD"; //Set desired date here.
} else {
    $dir_date = $_REQUEST['director_date'];
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel the answer is adequate, you should consider accepting it by clicking the check mark near the vote up/down buttons.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use javascript. However, you should use ajax or something to send it to the server.

```
function getMe(){
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var final = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<input.length;i++){
  if(input[i] == ''){
       final[input[i].name] = input[i].placeholder;
    } else {
       final[input[i].name] = input[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's wordpress so i need to use php. Thanks for your help though.Might come in handy when using ajax.I've given you a vote up

Answer (score 1):

Use your "placeholder" as the input's default value, then throw in some javascript to clear the value on focus and restore it on blur if empty.

`<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='placeholder text') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='placeholder text';" value="placeholder text">`

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5Tes/)

Comment: An easier approach to the question.Thanks @lafor

Comment: Could you please explain it. I want to use the above value. Echo, print or console.log it in other words

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var input = $(this).find('input[name=box]');
    if(input.val() == ""){
       input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));       
    };
});
```

DEMO FIDDLE (ignore the alert and return false): http://jsfiddle.net/TwY3E/